# Google geo code API not filtering results for Luxembourg

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder, geocode

I am filtering results for country code LU. Still getting results for US

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4321%2CLU&components=country%3ALU
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says that you cannot use country in both address and component filter. Doing that you can get unpredictable behavior.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

> Note: Each address component can only be specified either in the address parameter or as a component filter, but not both. Doing so may result in ZERO_RESULTS.

So, your query should be

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4321&components=country%3ALU&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Not sure what means 4321. If this is a postal code, I think it is missing from Google database, because

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A4321%7Ccountry%3ALU&key=YOUR_API_KEY

returns ZERO_RESULTS.

Comment: 4321 is a valid zipcode in Luxembourg, I don't know why google is not recognizing it. Is it a issue from their side?

Comment: You can use the "Report a problem" link to raise the data issue. 

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, you didn't make any big error; your API call should work ok. I believe this was a bug in Google's API, but it seems to be fixed now. (When I go to [the url you asked about](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4321%2CLU&components=country%3ALU), I get a proper JSON response that doesn't mention the US.) (If you reported the error, maybe you deserve the credit for getting it fixed! :)

The reason there were issues initially is because Google isn't an address verification or standardization service. Parsing is difficult for many reasons: there could be weird spellings or punctuation, for instance. Google is very good at parsing search terms.

But, there is an additional problem: how do we know which parts match the city or the state? "Georgia" is a state in the US and a country. Should "12 34 St Helena WA 85102" match "34 street" or a road named "St Helena"?

Address verification means to check an address against an authoritative database, such as postal office data and national records, resulting in a match to a real place. Address standardization means to format an address in the way the postal service standardizes it.

Thus, you will most likely run in to more issues like this in the future, especially if you're using addresses that are ambiguous. You may want to try address validation services, especially if you are working with mailing and shipping.

Fair disclosure: I'm an employee of [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com), an address validation company.